# Change formula of linked spreadsheet associated rows based on selection in master file

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks.  The first is the Master where the training plan is built.  The second has the linked fields from the Master and is named a variant of each person receiving training.

Each row in the Master has six additional columns, H through M where a specific person's name is selected by 'X'ing a cell.  (See screenshot)  This is how the link is activated on the associated child workbooks.

When a person's name is 'X'd in column H through M on the Master, the 'child' workbook (each person listed in H - M has one) (See screenshot) is then populated with information from the Master (columns N - R) with 'links'.  By removing the 'X' the text does not appear.  This is how I am managing what training a person is doing when.

#### Master Workbook

[image: Master Workbook]

#### Child Workbook

[image: Child Workbook]

The problem I have is in the formula of the 'link' to the Master workbook is based on a specifically selected column. In this case column H.

The specific formula in cell H6 for the 'child' file displayed is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!H$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$N$6)
```

I wish to create a way to have the column associated with the Master file dynamically change based on a selection of some sort.  At the present I have to change each 'child' workbook manually from !H$6 to !I$6, !J$6, etc on three times on 300 lines for the links to populate the correct information.  This is painful and takes a very long time.

Current:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!H$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$N$6)

=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!H$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$Q$6)

=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!H$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$R$6)
```

For example when I create Brenda and Brian's 'Child workbook' I have to change each entry from !H$6 to !I$6 or !M$6 depending on which workbook it is.

```
=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!I$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$N$6)

=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!I$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$Q$6)

=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!I$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$R$6)
```

I would like a way to have the column selected on the Master workbook (column that has the X) change the !H to !I or !J or !K, etc without having to change each line and text of each on each 'child' workbook.  The associated 'child' file already 'checks' for the 'X' in columns H thru M so that is already done.

MY GOAL:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!(Some Variable based on selection)$6)," ",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$Q$6)
```

So, in looking at the Master you can see that the Skill Trained On of 'Adding Users' has Chad (column H), Brenda (column J), and Brian (column M) 'X'd.  The above should change dynamically based on which X is selected.

Chad's (Child Workbook) references all 'Master linked' fields (Columns N-R) with some variable that indicates column H.   Brenda's indicates Column J, and Brian's indicates Column M.  4

[image]

Comment: look at [Match](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function. And [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)

Comment: Scott, I watched both videos (Match & OFFSET) and am somewhat (a lot) confused on how these commands would resolve my issue?  Can you put some context to your response to assist me in reference to the following:   Cell H6, Cell I6 - both are checked.  Child workbook Chad is working since it uses Cell H6 in the formula.  Child workbook Brenda is not working and I am not sure how to use Match & OFFSET to help me?  Sorry for not understanding what you are telling me.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have all the columns and rows shown in your pictures, so you may need to tweak the exact cell references, but try this out:

Following assumptions:

`Child` name is in cell `E1` of child workbook.
'Child` names start in row 3 of master workbook.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$H$3,Row()-3,MATCH(E1,'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$H$3:$M$3,0)-1))),"",'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!Q$6)
```

To break it down:

`MATCH(E1,'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$H$3:$M$3,0))` will match column where the child name in the master sheet appears in `H3:M3`.

`OFFSET('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$H$3,Row()-3,MATCH ... -1)` will offset the number of columns from `H3` in master book by the number of columns *(the minus 1 is needed because we matched on the exact column set and offset on the set)*  and the number of rows as you go down the line *(this may need adjusting)*.

The rest I think is self-explantory.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I will work with your 'instructions' and report back my results.  Thanks & GOD Bless!

Comment: Ok.  After a few hours I was able to get the 'Match' to work as expected and return the # associated with the persons' name when a certain cell is blank.  As I change the name the number changes so that is working great from the linked Master workbook.  I am not however grasping the concept of the OFFSET portion of your comment.  Would it be possible for me to email you both the master and one of the 'child' files so you can see what I am seeing?

Comment: @ChadR.Kleve = `OFFSET(cell_range,number_of_rows,number_of_columns,[height],[width])` ... height and width can be ignored here ... if you offset cell A1 by 2 rows and 1 column, it returns the value in cell B3. So if you the match occurs in column 3, you offset H3 by 3 columns and whatever row your formula is on minus 3 (because the names start on row 3). Again, this may need a bit of tweaking, but if that doesn't help, write back again.

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK('[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!J15),"",OFFSET(H6,MATCH(H1,'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$H$3:$M$3,0),MATCH(H1,H6:L6,0)))  - This returns a N/A response. I think I am getting closer...

Comment: The first match I think is wrong: `MATCH(H1,'[Redesigned Plan - Master.xlsx]Training'!$H$3:$M$3,0)` this is a row offset and you have column count. Maybe I am not remembering the data correctly. To troubleshooting, place the row offset number you *know* it should be and then work to find a good way to use a formula to get that number from the cell locations and such.

Comment: Scott, I spent the better part of the day learning the process through much trial and error.  I have a 'working solution' however it needs someone to look at it.  When I select a different person (child file) and put their name in the H1 cell the information does not populate as expected.  May I email you both the Master & Child so you can see what I am talking about?  I could really use your expertise. I believe I am close to getting this problem resolved and am VERY grateful for your assistance.  Thanks & GOD Bless, Chad

Comment: @ChadR.Kleve - i will send my mail once you get you back online. let me know you're here and I'll send it (and delete it again very quickly)

Comment: Scott, an observation I made this morning is the 'child' record shows all linked fields as #VALUE! when the 'master' workbook is closed.  This is a potential problem with how I plan to use the 'child' workbooks.  Is there something that I need to do different to show the data in the fields even though the linked 'master' workbook is closed?